# How to filter id and name of who does not have a specific value in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
id      name       update
1      andre       torch2
2      paulo       stock_opt
3      Manuela     length
1      andre       stock
3      Manuela     torch2
```

how can I query the **id** and **name** of who does not have torch2 on `update` column?

the output should be:

```
id      name       update  
2      paulo       stock_opt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Get all groups by `id` and `name` if `torch2` not exist by compare with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and test by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['update'].ne('torch2').groupby([df['id'],df['name']]).transform('all')]
print (df1)
   id   name     update
1   2  paulo  stock_opt
```

Or create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), test if equal `torch2` and filter out indices in [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
s = df.set_index(['id','name'])['update']
df1 = df[~s.index.isin(s.index[s.eq('torch2')])]
print (df1)
   id   name     update
1   2  paulo  stock_opt
```

For opposite compare by equal and test if at least one match by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html):

```
df2 = df[df['update'].eq('torch2').groupby([df['id'],df['name']]).transform('any')]
print (df2)
   id     name  update
0   1    andre  torch2
2   3  Manuela  length
3   1    andre   stock
4   3  Manuela  torch2
```

Or remove `~` for invert mask:

```
s = df.set_index(['id','name'])['update']
df2 = df[s.index.isin(s.index[s.eq('torch2')])]
print (df2)
   id     name  update
0   1    andre  torch2
2   3  Manuela  length
3   1    andre   stock
4   3  Manuela  torch2
```

Comment: Thanks.   Please, and is there a way to do the opposite, I mean query all name and id that DOES have torch2?